# Turning a sentence from first to second person

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I'm trying to write a script in Python using nltk which changes a sentence from second person to first person.
Example: the sentence

```
I went to see Avatar and you came with me
```

should become

```
You went to see Avatar and I came with you
```

Is there a built-in function in nltk that does this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There shouldn't be too many forms of personal and possessive pronouns in English. If you create a dictionary of correspondence between 1st and 2nd person forms, you can then tokenize the original sentence and replace the words that are in the dictionary:

```
forms = {"am" : "are", "are" : "am", 'i' : 'you', 'my' : 'yours', 'me' : 'you', 'mine' : 'yours', 'you' : 'I', 'your' : 'my', 'yours' : 'mine'} # More?
def translate(word):
  if word.lower() in forms: return forms[word.lower()]
  return word

sent = 'You went to see Avatar, and I came with you.'
result = ' '.join([translate(word) for word in nltk.wordpunct_tokenize(sent)])
print(result.caputalize())
# I went to see avatar , and you came with i .
```

Because of the ambiguity of `you` you probably cannot get any better results.

Comment: "you came with i" is not grammatically correct, though

Comment: As I said, because of the ambiguity of "you" in English you probably cannot do any better.

Comment: "I am the I am" -> "You am the you am" ;P

Comment: @alvas First, the dictionary is not complete. Second, your example is not correct even before the translation.

Comment: The example was to show that I don't think you can do sentence to sentence translation from first person by simple replacement. Imagine the classic case of "I take my hats off you" -> "You take your hats off I"? If you use "you"->"me", it would correct but you would have strange phenomena like "You don't like me" -> "me don't like you". Note that in a [nominative-accusative language the S (subject) receives different grammatical treatment from the O (direct object)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominative–accusative_language).

Comment: Look at the last line of my answer - I made exactly the same point.

Comment: I don't even think this is an answerable question on stackoverflow =) (at least not without someone conducting experiments and writing a full research paper).

Comment: @alvas you're right. In facts my original question was just about an eventual framework available to solve it, not a scientific approach to the problem. Anyway, I think that DYZ's approach is the best thing you can do without training a model for the problem. About your correction, though, I am the I am is turned to "You are the you are", which is equally wrong but nonetheless consistent. A correct phrase like "I am who I am" would be turned to "You are who you are" which is actually correct

Answer (score 1):

Um, not sure about using a built in function, but you can try `.replace()`

For example:

```
.replace("I","You")
```

would change every "I" in the string to  "You"

Comment: Yeah, I thought about it! But the problem is that I should also handle cases like me, mine, yours...not to mention verbs like I am which should turn to you are! It's not impossible, you just have to carefully think about the set of replacements, but a built-in function would have helped!

Comment: Don't think that works for this sentence "Ice scream, I like" -> "Youce scream, You like". =(

Comment: Right, maybe not the best approach to it, but it can work. I don't think there is an easier way to do it currently.